# maximum setlocal recursion level reached for heroku in windows

Tags: laravel, heroku, hosting

[image]

I am trying to host a small app in heroku. The app is already up. Now when I was trying to push additional changes and hence logging; I am getting this error in my cmd.

The app is in laravel 5.4. I am running windows 10. And I am relatively new to hosting and heroku.

What might be the possible solution to the problem?

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same problem today and I think it is related to the automatic Heroku CLI update.

I managed to fix it by changing this file: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku\client\7.0.15\bin\heroku.cmd`

On line 4 it was:

```
if not "%HEROKU_REDIRECTED%"=="1" if exist "%LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku\client\bin\heroku.cmd" (
```

and I changed it to:

```
if not %HEROKU_REDIRECTED%=="1" if exist "%LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku\client\bin\heroku.cmd" (
```

Basically when `%HEROKU_REDIRECTED%` was wrapped in double quotes first if statement always evaluated to true, causing recursion.

Comment: For me, i had to comment this line to get it working: `set HEROKU_REDIRECTED="1"`. My Heroku version was `heroku/7.0.25 win32-x64 node-v10.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Heroku posted an update and fix for this:

https://help.heroku.com/FMA2YNC8/heroku-cli-windows-v7-setlocal-recursion-error

> The recursion error has been patched in version 7.0.13, however the
>   bug may render earlier versions of the CLI unusable. To fix this,
>   delete the CLI client folder at
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Local\heroku\client then run heroku
>   update.

Comment: Deleting the client folder let me run the update command, but on completion of the update, it immediately went back to producing the recursion error. Czarek's solution above worked on the latest version (7.0.15).

Comment: I was actually having Heroku version `heroku/7.0.25 win32-x64 node-v10.0.0` but was still facing issue. @Czarek solution helped me. I have anyways updated the CLI. Thanks for the link. :)